# Additional options for MarionetteJS CollectionView

Tags: marionette

I have no idea what am I missing here but I'm not able to pass additional parameter to a CollectionView, like so:

View definition is very basic:

```
class UI.Elements extends App.Views.CollectionView
  itemView: UI.Element
```

And then instantiated with these options:

```
getUIsView: (uiobjects, itemView) ->
  options = 
    collection: uiobjects
    variationView: itemView

  new App.VariationsApp.UI.Elements options
```

With this code the view is being created fine, except the `variationView` is no where to be found. From backbone documentation:

> When creating a new View, the options you pass — after being merged into any default options already present on the view — are attached to the view as **this.options** for future reference

But my `CollectionView` doesn't have `options` property on itself.

Really, I don't have any idea what am I doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any parameter you provide your view that aren't recognized as Backbone/Marionette options will be attached to `this.options` within the view. So you should have access to the `variationView` by accessing `this.options.variationView`.

If you need to access that information in the template, you need to pass it along by writing a `serializeData` function.

You can see an example of this in practice here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/common/views.js

Comment: That is exactly what I expected and tried. But as I mentioned in my question, my `CollectionView` is missing the `options` property. I have no idea why…

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted a jsFiddle that SO users can look at.

Comment: I followed your advice to setup jsFiddle. Pulled backbone and marionette from a cdn, separated the part of my code in question… and it worked. The only difference was that I have development (uncompressed) versions of these libraries in my app. When I switched backbone to it's compressed version, everything worked as expected. It just boggles my mind why is that. Anyway, I'm accepting your answer since it with your comment led me to figuring this out. Thank you.